# neo4j query result changed base on return node and properties

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neo4j-driver

I have a query with 2 different return nodes. My question is why when I return m2 node, result will change and when remove **m2** node from return statement, result will change too. result **dcount** change by removing or adding m2. my question is why?!!

first query with **m2** in return statement:

```
MATCH (a1:Example)<-[r1:REL_EXAMPLE]-(a2:Example),
      (a1)-[:REL_2_EXAMPLE]->(m1:Mexample),
      (a2)-[:REL_2_EXAMPLE]->(m2:Mexample)
WHERE a1.key = 123456
      AND a2.key <> a1.key
      AND (r1.delta < 300 AND r1.delta > 20)
      AND ((a1.love <> 0 OR a2.love <> 0) OR (abs(a1.love - a2.love) < 0.1))
WITH a1,a2,m1,m2,r1, CASE
WHEN exists((m1)<-[:REL_2_EXAMPLE]-(a2)) OR exists((m2)<-[:REL_2_EXAMPLE]-(a1)) THEN 0.20
      ELSE 1
  END AS factor
RETURN count(r1) * factor as dcount,a2.title as anode, a2.key as id, m2.full_name ORDER BY dcount DESC LIMIT 30;
```

second query without **m2**:

```
MATCH (a1:Example)<-[r1:REL_EXAMPLE]-(a2:Example),
      (a1)-[:REL_2_EXAMPLE]->(m1:Mexample),
      (a2)-[:REL_2_EXAMPLE]->(m2:Mexample)
WHERE a1.key = 123456
      AND a2.key <> a1.key
      AND (r1.delta < 300 AND r1.delta > 20)
      AND ((a1.love <> 0 OR a2.love <> 0) OR (abs(a1.love - a2.love) < 0.1))
WITH a1,a2,m1,m2,r1, CASE
WHEN exists((m1)<-[:REL_2_EXAMPLE]-(a2)) OR exists((m2)<-[:REL_2_EXAMPLE]-(a1)) THEN 0.20
      ELSE 1
  END AS factor
RETURN count(r1) * factor as dcount,a2.title as anode, a2.key as id ORDER BY dcount DESC LIMIT 30;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are performing an aggregation operation in the return statement. In the first query with `m2` in the return statement.

```
RETURN count(r1) * factor as dcount,a2.title as anode, a2.key as id, m2.full_name ORDER BY dcount DESC LIMIT 30;
```

`dcount` is calculated for each distinct combination of `a2.title`, `a2.key` and `m2.full_name`.

In the second query, with the return statement

```
RETURN count(r1) * factor as dcount,a2.title as anode, a2.key as id ORDER BY dcount DESC LIMIT 30;
```

`dcount` is calculated, for each distinct combination of `a2.title` and `a2.key`, since the aggregation criteria for each query is different, hence the results are different.